# Final Cut Pro best export settings for h.264 html5 playback - optimize for download / streaming

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js, finalcut

What are the best settings in Final Cut Pro when intending to use video.js for html5 playback?

Specifically, what's the deal with "Optimized: For Download" or "Optimized: For Streaming"? [The documentation is fuzzy](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=106&section=5&tasks=true). You can see the setting in the screenshot under "Standard Video Compression Settings".

Presumably "optimize for streaming" writes the metadata to the head of the file. Vimeo and [Brightcove recommend](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/exporting-high-quality-source-file-using-final-cut-pro-7) "optimize for download". Why? For a progressive download don't we want metadata at the head? Why, according to the Apple documentation, is "optimize for streaming" bad otherwise?

Comment: Neither link mentions a "optimize for download" setting, just "optimize for streaming" which does what you think it does.

Comment: In the Apple documentation you can see the dropdown which is selected to "Optimized: For Download".

Unfortunately, I don't know what "Optimized: For Streaming" does. We have a file, which contains bits of video (in a codec), bit of audio (also encoded), and metadata. How does "optimize for streaming" alter the bits? The codec is already selected.